# How to reference to the instance of class owning another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

i have a a Map class with a property camera which is another custom class MapCamera.

The MapCamera has five properties:

_x

_y

map - a reference to the instance of Map owning this MapCamera

offsetX

offsetY

how do i reference to the instance of Map owning this MapCamera?

Map.as:

```
package  {

    import MapCamera;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Map extends Sprite {

        public var camera:MapCamera = new MapCamera(this);

        public function Map() {
            // constructor code
            }

    }

}
```

MapCamera.as:

```
package  {

    import Map;

    public class MapCamera {

        private var _x:Number;
        private var _y:Number;
        public var map:Map // a reference to the instance of Map owning this MapCamera
        public var offsetX:Number;
        public var offsetY:Number;

        public function get x():Number{ return _x; }
        public function get y():Number{ return _y; }

        public function set x(n:Number):void
        {
            _x = n;
            map.x = -(_x + offsetX);
        }

        public function set y(n:Number):void
        {
            _y = n;
        map.y = -(_y + offsetY);
        }

        public function MapCamera(m:Map) {
            // constructor code
            map = m;
        }

    }

}
```

But i get this error: 
Map.as, Line 8, Column 47   1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly you try to pass the instantiated MAP object as a reference into the MAPCAMERA class when you create the MAP.

Your problem here really is that when you call

```
public var camera:MapCamera = new MapCamera(this);
```

You have not actually created the instance of the class yet. Actionscript will create the class global objects before running the constructor so the required objected are available when the constructor runs.

You have to move your code into the Map constructor in this case, else you will only pass the CLASS reference to your camera, not its instance.

```
public function MapCamera(m:Map)
```

The function call will not give you an error since m is passed as a class, and regardless of you passing the class or its instance m:Map of course would accept it as they are both valid. Try to debug your code and look at what m looks like when you try to call the MapCamera constructor (Simply set a breakpoint there). The difference will become obvious.

It is of course perfectly valid  to do so, for example if you want to dynamically create instances of an existing class object and pass the class and not the constructor.

Do this instead:

```
public var camera:MapCamera;

public function Map()
{
        camera = new MapCamera(this);
}
```